# How can I make Supervisor run on a different port than the default 6001?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

I have a laravel project and I am using Laravel-Websockets which run under the port 6001.
However, I'm installing Supervisor to help run commands automatically, but the Supervisor is running on the same 6001 port and I get
`Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:6001": Address already in use (EADDRINUSE)`

Is there any way to change the Supervisor and make it run under another port?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the [inet_http_server](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#inet-http-server-section-values) documentation help at all, if not why not consider changing the port that Websockets uses?

Comment: Thank you @Peppermintology I already did that.
But it was something else more complex than this one

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here am I with an answer after a few hours of research.

Actually, the problem depends whether you use a Control Panel for your server.
This is important because all default paths are replaced in case you use one (such as domain_name can be under /www/wwwroot/domain_name or PHP directory can be in another PATH managed by the Control Panel)

Mine is AAA panel, so I was loading the wrong PHP on my program, and I had to put the real actual path of the PHP instead of `/usr/bin/php`

Consider cleaning the entire cache on laravel before running the supervisorctl again. (sudo php artisan ptimize:clear)